# How to get the speech with desired start position and end position from .wav file in java?

Tags: java

May I know how to get the speech with desired start position and end position from the speech wav file in java?
I would like to concatenate two wav file after cutting with desired positions.
I found recommended code for cutting cutting a wave file.
This has originally been answered by [Martin Dow.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66722/martin-dow)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

class AudioFileProcessor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  copyAudio("/tmp/uke.wav", "/tmp/uke-shortened.wav", 2, 1);
}

public static void copyAudio(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, int startSecond, int secondsToCopy) {
AudioInputStream inputStream = null;
AudioInputStream shortenedStream = null;
try {
  File file = new File(sourceFileName);
  AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
  AudioFormat format = fileFormat.getFormat();
  inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
  int bytesPerSecond = format.getFrameSize() * (int)format.getFrameRate();
  inputStream.skip(startSecond * bytesPerSecond);
  long framesOfAudioToCopy = secondsToCopy * (int)format.getFrameRate();
  shortenedStream = new AudioInputStream(inputStream, format, framesOfAudioToCopy);
  File destinationFile = new File(destinationFileName);
  AudioSystem.write(shortenedStream, fileFormat.getType(), destinationFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
  println(e);
} finally {
  if (inputStream != null) try { inputStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) { println(e); }
  if (shortenedStream != null) try { shortenedStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) { println(e); }
 }
}
```

In this code, the skip method only accepted long value. I want to put the second with double value. It is not okay for me. Therefore, please suggest me, to cut the speech wav file with desired positions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to implement? And some sample code that you can not understand?

Comment: The skip method accepts a number of bytes, which should be an integer. Since the result of `startSecond * bytesPerSecond` is a `Double`, you will have to floor, round or ceil it. I suppose `Math.floor` would be the best in your case.

Comment: [@Aaron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron) - In my system, the entire duration for speech file is 0.318s. I want to cut 0.159s to the end of the speech file. Therefore,my input 'startSecond' is 0.159s. At that time, the 'startSecond' is 0 when I use _Math.floor(0.159)_. I cannot get the desired position for cutting. How should I do?

Comment: Don't floor the second, floor the result of second * byteRate : `inputStream.skip(Math.floor(startSecond * bytesPerSecond));`

Comment: I cannot solve until now

Comment: Now , I can solve it. Thanks for all.